# Starting a trust fund in an EU country

Tags: european-union, europe, trusts

I'm in a sudden and unfortunate need of starting a trust fund (money being the only asset) in an EU country (I'm afraid I need to rule out UK as an option) for a minor (not a relative of mine) that would receive it upon reaching a certain state of adulthood (the target age is not clear right now but let's assume in 4-6 years). There would be 2 or 3 primary settlors (including me) who would be the trustees at the same time, and possibly a couple of minor settlors. One of the issues is the following:

1. I come from the country **A**, live in the country **B** but intend to move to the country **C** within an year.
2. **Trustee #2** comes from the country **D** but also lives in the country **B**.
3. **Trustee #3** comes from the country **D** but lives in the country **E**.
4. The **beneficiary** comes from the country **D** but would probably move to the country **E** or **other country** before being eligible to receive any money.

I believe that this is such a wild mix of (EU) countries that there is no clear benefit in establishing the trust fund in any of them (which is one of the reasons why I purposefully left out real country names). It got me thinking:

**Q: Is there an EU country which would be particularly suitable as the location of the trust fund?**

The idea is that it might be better to find a country which would be suitable based on some objective criteria instead of current location of trustees and/or beneficiary. Mainly:

1. Country's **law** regarding trusts.
2. Established **tradition** of trusts (IMHO in some EU countries the trusts are a fairly recent thing).
3. Favorable **taxation** (or lack of).
4. **Interest** - it would be good if the money could generate some money, if nothing else then to beat inflation.

#### Edits

1. A good question coming from the comments is whether I and other **settlors/trustees would actually be eligible to open/run a trust fund in a country that we are not residents of**. I don't know which countries would present any legal hurdles but my current believe is that EU citizens should not have insurmountable obstacles in other EU countries - this is actually one of the main reasons why I limited the choice to EU countries only.
2. I understand it's not easy or even possible to research an answer for this question just by Googling. This is the reason why the **bounty targets people who have prior knowledge of this topic**.
3. I also understand that being familiar with trust funds in **all EU countries** is pretty much impossible. *Out of the following N countries I'd recommend country X because of this and that* would be a good answer.

Comment: Could you use Luxembourg ??

Comment: @Fattie Yes, I believe so, even though I don't know which countries would have any legal hurdles for non-residents. However, I do have some friends living there so they could possibly help to facilitate this.

Comment: I think you are going to need paid-for advice for this.

Comment: @MartinBonner A lawyer will certainly be needed to setup the trust. The thing is that IMHO they are typically familiar with the trusts of a country they work at while I am trying to narrow down which country to aim at. But yes, I'd consider a paid advice if I find somebody who has international insight into trust funds.

Comment: From a little web-searching, I've not found a generic "across Europe" comparison; the closest mention I've found is [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_law#Region_variations) which says "_Trust law in civil law jurisdictions, generally including Continental Europe only exists in a limited number of jurisdictions [...]. The trust may however be recognized as an instrument of foreign law in conflict of laws cases_" (which reinforces your "_in some EU countries the trusts are a fairly recent thing_" observation). [**cont**]

Comment: [**cont**] While I understand your reluctance to name **A**, **B**, etc., short of someone trawling the legal position in all 27 states (omitting the UK), you might need to name a smaller number of candidates to get a reasonable chance at an answer.

Comment: @TripeHound I totally share your sentiment but this not much of **"make comparison of all 27 countries"** but rather **"propose 1 or 2 countries backed by some reasoning"**. Limiting the choice to a defined set of countries would negate the premise of _"it might be better to find a country which would be suitable based on some objective criteria instead of current location of trustees and/or beneficiary"_ and would also make the question less valuable for other people needing an answer in future.

Comment: @tmt I fully understand where you're coming from... my point is that to get your "_1 or 2 countries backed by reasoning_" then _either_ someone on PF&M needs to already know the rules of all 27 countries (_possible_, but probably unlikely), or they need to read up on the rules of all 27. There doesn't (after a brief search) appear to be an online "ready-made" comparison of all 27 (though I could have missed such a list), so someone would have to dig through each country in turn (assuming such info exists). Again... someone _might_ want to do this, but probably not.

Comment: @TripeHound I agree that digging for this information would be a mammoth task. This is why the bounty targets people who have prior knowledge of this topic. I accept that there might be no such person on this site. It's a long shot which is why I gambled almost all the reputation points I had.

Comment: I have no idea about trusts, so this is only a comment. But: besides possible restrictions of a resident of B starting a trust in F, you may have to make sure the trust does not unintentionally move to another country due to the trustees managing the trust from where they reside: IIRC a foundation is considered to be located (for e.g. tax purposes) where its management actually takes place (not necessarily where the managers are residing or physically present, but where the management structure such as archives etc. are located).

Comment: If you've not seen it, [How to Protect Your Assets with an Offshore Trust](https://nomadcapitalist.com/offshore-trust/) might be of some interest, although of non-UK, EU countries it only explicitly mentions France.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve? I understand you want to put cash-money that belongs to a minor (or young adult >= 18 years?) on a bank account and earn interests for 4 to 6 years. For example in Germany, the legal guardians would simply open a bank account in the name of the minor. The minor will be able to access the money when 18. If the legal guardians are unavailable, you need to cooperate with a family/guardianship court. Taxation in most industrialized countries will allways involve (at least) the country of residence of the beneficiary; citizenship does not matter.